# Overlap between a list of stocks and ETF

Tags: etf

I have a list of 50 stock symbols. I am wondering if there is any tool to find out the best overlap between those stock symbols with 1500+ ETFs available in the US. The idea is to buy a fund instead of all the stocks separately which is a tedious process. For example AAPL, MSFT, AMZN, GOOG, FB etc overlaps well with QQQ. I want to find it out for any list of stock symbols.

Comment: The list of symbols, without weights, will match dozens of funds since it takes an ETF a single share to "qualify". E.g. some fund with 1 share of  AAPL, MSFT, AMZN, GOOG, FB each and 10 million shares of another symbol will overlap just like QQQ. Need to introduce weights into the equation.

Comment: A few years ago Interactive Brokers had a program that automatically suggested "similar" ETFs based on the stocks in my account. The suggestions were not very helpful, too generic (eg. SPY) and did not take into account why I owned that stock (I could own AAPL bcause it is a Tech Stock, or bc it is a big cap or because I like companies from Calif. etc. etc.). Program does not know what I see in AAPL. It seems that IB stopped doing this, maybe I was not the only 1 who found it useless.

Comment: I am talking about mostly small caps overlap with ETFs. Large caps overlaps are obvious and not very helpful.

Comment: Without weights this is mostly a Linux bash scripting exercise. Grep, awk, and wc -l the ConstituentData42.csv file from https://masterdatareports.com/

Comment: Good that something like this exists. I just made a small db with all iShares ETF holdings.